# How to listen to keyboard events in electron without interrupting default behavior?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, keyboard-events

I was trying to listen to `Ctrl-C` event using electron `globalShortcut` module, but as it seems, electron is re-writing default behavior automatically (without features like `preventDefault` in plain javascript).

Here's what I did:

```js
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const test: boolean = globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+C', () => {
    console.log('Test.')
  })

  /* ... */
})
```

Is there an another way to listen to global keyboard shortcut events using electron without interrupting their default behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be [Electron's expected behaviour](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8491#issuecomment-274790124)

You can use [iohook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iohook) to capture key presses instead of Electron's `globalShortcut` module